# MongoDB select count

Tags: mongodb

I have the following database

```
{"userName":"John Smith", "followers":8075,"body":"my text 1","confirmed":"no"}
{"userName":"james Bond", "followers":819, "body":"my text 2", "confirmed":"yes"}
{"userName":"Julia Roberts","followers":3882,"body":"my text 3","confirmed":"yes"}
{"userName":"Jamal David","followers":6531, "body":"my text 4","confirmed":"yes"}
{"userName":"jane fonda","followers":3941, "body":"my text 5","confirmed":"no"}
```

I need to count number of followers whose name starts with Ja (**case-insensitive**)

I'm trying to do this, but this selection gives me all matching lines.

```
db.collections.find( { $and:[{followers: { $gte: 0 } }, {"userName" : {$regex :/^Ja/i}}  ]})
```

And this only gives total number of matching lines

```
db.collections.find( { $and:[{followers: { $gte: 0 } }, {"userName" : {$regex :/^Ja/i}}  ]}).count()
```

How can I extract number of followers for the matching lines (james, Jamal, jane)?

Comment: Not sure. Tried both ways on the big data set and the results are different.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.collections.aggregate([{
$match:{"userName":{$regex :/^Ja/i}}
},
{$group:{
_id:null,
followers: {$sum: "$followers"}
}}])
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: As per  your requirement you want to count number of followers whose name start with "ja", so the query says first match the records which username start with "ja" then use $group to sum of all followers of all records.Refer this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/ and you will understand the query